# Manually adjust alpha after plot is created?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I would like to manually adjust the alpha of ggplot object.  There is function scale_alpha_manual but it does not seem to affect the color.  Here is an code example.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)), size=12)
p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green")) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, .5, .1)) # does nothing
```

edit: the issue is that the ggplot has already been created and I want to manipulate the alpha after the fact.  I also tried to change the label, for example, `p$labels$alpha = "factor(cyl)"` but that does not work neither.

[image]

Comment: you need `alpha = factor(cyl)` in `aes` to use `scale_alpha_manual`

Comment: Would `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$alpha <- 0.5` suffice?

Comment: @teunbrand excellent! this works.

Comment: @teunbrand I looked for this solution FOREVER and this did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the geom_point(aes(alpha= xxxx)). I think adding that will help you create a custom alpha value after the fact. Hope that helps!

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour= as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(size=12, aes(alpha= as.factor(cyl))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("chocolate1","goldenrod","pink"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.6, 0.3, .7),guide=F)
```

Comment: thanks - I'm aware that I can set the alpha in the aes, however the issue here is that I have to do it after the fact.  Sorry for the confusion - I added this to my edit.